# Is this correct usage of "unable"?

Tags: sentence-patterns

I sent an email to my recruiter  asking how to track my application online and recruiter said this in an email -

> Unfortunately you are unable to track your application online.

Is this sentence correct? I feel the following gives the correct meaning.

> Unfortunately, you won't be able to track your application online.

Comment: Answers depend on definition of and discussion of *unable* and are not merely a matter of opinion. Leave open.

Comment: Could you accept that while that wording would not be a common choice, there's nothing actually wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with *able*:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/able)
> *able*
> to have the necessary physical strength, mental power, skill, time, money, or opportunity to do something

to be *unable* is to be not able.

Your reasonable doubts are supported by the first notions in this definition - not to have the *strength, skill, mental power, time or money*. These are all attributes the applicant may lack.

However, not to have the *opportunity* corresponds to the usage in your first text, which may be understood to say "*Unfortunately you have no opportunity (=are unable) to track your application online*". This reflects a lack in the recruiting system, not in the applicant. Presumably the recruitment system gives no tracking access to applicants, so they have no opportunity to do so - they are unable.

From this viewpoint, your first text is acceptable, as is your second.

Comment: Yes, bureaucracy finds no incentive to be clear or simple. You are unable because our system won't allow it (oh, the active voice takes responsibility.) That means we disabled you...oops. Actually, we made sure you are unable. It's not incorrect, yet unfriendly.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Now you have me imagining those funny examples where a phrase was translated to another language and then translated back. This could result in "you are crippled from tracking your application"

Comment: With more rounds of translations , it might become "you were crippled because you followed the Document" & "we broke your bones for daring to follow" & "we broke your bones for stalking" , @Barmar

Comment: This is getting funny. I wish I could give even more funny translation :D